# fromHtml: Different behaviour on JellyBean and KitKat (and above)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.1-jelly-bean, fromhtml

I am using `fromHtml` to display formatted text (bold italic etc) in `TextView`. However, I found it's behaviour is different on JellyBean (4.1.2) and KitKat(4.4.2)

Here is code:

```
    String myHtml = "<b>hello</b>&#128516;";
    Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(myHtml, null, null);
```

Here html string has `&#128516;` which is unicode for an emoji. Now after calling `fromHtml` it returns following value on KitKat (and above):

```
spanned = hello
```

Here is screenshot of Android Studio for the same:

[image]

This is expected behaviour as we can see corresponding emoji in `spanned`.

But on JellyBean the same call returns following value:

```
spanned = hello��
```

Here is screenshot:

[image]

This is indeed not expected and driving me nuts. I don't know what I am doing wrong. If anyone having idea please can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, root of this problem was in `Html.toHtml` which I had used to convert text in `TextView` to html. I used custom `toHtml`and this problem solved. I used `.toHtml`written in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35837723/1911652) answer. Indeed it is great solution. I wonder how Android's original `Html.toHtml` is so lame and defective.

Answer (score 0):

add [this](https://github.com/delight-im/Emoji/tree/master/Android/src) java file in your `src` and add [this](https://github.com/delight-im/Emoji/tree/master/Android/assets/fonts) font `.ttf` file in `assets dir`

now use this like below

```
String myHtml = "<b>hello</b>&#128516;";
Spanned spanned = AndroidEmoji.ensure(myHtml);
```

for more check here [gitcode.](https://github.com/delight-im/Emoji/tree/master/Android)

Comment: Thanks for answer but this is for Android version below 4.1.1. Mine is JellyBean (4.1.2) so it is not working for me :(